# Which is faster: calculation or assignment

Tags: ruby, time, variable-assignment

I'm optimizing some code. I need the sum of `a+b+c` and `x+y+z`, and I will calculate the minimum and maximum of these variables. Using `minmax` is not an option. I will do these calculations separately.

Which of the following code blocks is quicker?

```
min, max = 0, 0
max = [max, a + b + c, x + y + z].max
min = [min, a + b + c, x + y + z].min
```

Or I could do something like this:

```
min, max = 0, 0
sum, sum2 = a + b + c,  x + y + z

max = [max, sum, sum2].max
min = [min, sum, sum2].min
```

Is the assignment and then call of these variables faster than just calculating them as I need them? If I need these sums later in the same scope, it is cleaner to assign variables for readability.

I am just curious on the inner workings of Ruby, more than I am the process of development.

Comment: _"using minmax is not an option"_ – why not?

Comment: I'm mainly asking this question to determine what is faster in ruby, assignment or calculation, and why. Not to calculate actual minimums or maximums.

Comment: If `min` and `max` are not relevant to your example, you could remove the calls and just create the two arrays. However, this level of optimization is likely useless. I'd go with the code that's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily test this using [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

```
require 'benchmark'

a, b, c, x, y, z = [1,3,5,7,9,11]

n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm do |bench|
  bench.report("1") { 
    n.times do 
      min, max = 0, 0;
      max = [max, a + b + c, x + y + z].max;
      min = [min, a + b + c, x + y + z].min;
    end
  }
  bench.report("2") { 
    n.times do
      min, max = 0, 0;
      sum, sum2 = a + b + c,  x + y + z;
      max = [max, sum, sum2].max;
      min = [min, sum, sum2].min;
    end
  }
end
```

which results in

```
bash-3.2$ ruby rubyspeed.rb
       user     system      total        real
1  0.160000   0.000000   0.160000 (  0.154085)
2  0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.119762)
bash-3.2$
```

so the second would be faster. It's probably the repeated computation of `a + b + c` and `x + y + z` that's causing this.

Comment: Interesting... thank you very much. I haven't used much of this 'benchmark' technique. I'll have to look into it more. Thanks!

Comment: I just figured Ruby would probably have something similar to Python's `timeit` and it did. You're welcome!